# PHP database validation

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Book A Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Book A Table</h1>



<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $numErr=$dateErr = $timeErr = $personsErr="";
$name = $email = $num= $date = $time = $persons = $comment= "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
   }
   if (empty($_POST["num"])) {
     $numErr = "Number is required";
   } else {
     $num = test_input($_POST["num"]);
     if (!preg_match("([0-9])", $num)) {
      $numErr = "Enter numbers only"; 
    }
   }



   if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
     $dateErr = "Date is required";
   } else {
     $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
   }



   if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
     $timeErr = "Time is required";
   } else {
     $time = test_input($_POST["time"]);
   }
   if (empty($_POST["persons"])) {
     $personsErr = "Number of persons is required";
   } else {
     $persons = test_input($_POST["persons"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

    <form action="DBInput.php" method="POST"  />

    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Full Name<br> <input type="text" name="name">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail<br> <input type="text" name="email">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Contact Number<br> <input type="text" name="num">
   <span class="error">*<?php echo $numErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Reservation Date<br> <input type="date" name="date">
   <span class="error">*<?php echo $dateErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Reservation Time<br>(Mon - Thur: 18:00 - 23:00 Fri - Sun: 12:00 - 00:00)<br> <input type="time" name="time">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $timeErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Number of Persons<br> <input type="text" name="persons">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $personsErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
Comments<br><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>





</body>
</html>
```

What I am doing in the above code is creating a form and inputting it into a database. This is working perfectly. However I would like to add validation so that if the user does not enter all the required fields, it wont be stored in the database.

I have only started PHP this week and so im a begginner. Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Since you are not using any framework and even not object-oriented approach, what you did is enough. Why aren't you happy with it?

Comment: Are you asking us to give you a "better" way of doing this?  If that is the case, how would you define "better"?  More reusable? Faster? Comments on best practices?  I'm not really sure what your question is, what you have looks functional and what you're doing is basic enough that context is pretty important in determining what might be a better approach.  Is there a specific section of your code you're unhappy with?

Comment: the problem is.. if the required fields are left empty a new record is still created in the database. i would like all the required fields to be filled in before a neww record is made

Comment: @GentlemanMax ^^^^^^

Comment: @chris, I don't actually see in your code where you are writing it to the database.  What you would basically do is have a variable `$writeDB = true` and then if any of your empty checks fail you set `$writeDB=false`.  Then just wrap your db writing function in `if($writeDB){//write to database here}`

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you something different:

Create a file that keeps an array with validation rules of all the fields you have in your database, table by table:

fields.php

```
return [
    'users' => [ // Let's say your table is called `users`
        'name' => [
             'required', // This means the field is required
         ],
         'email' => [
             'email' // email validator
         ]
        // etc...
    ]
    // etc...
];
```

Then create another file with validator functions:

validator.php

```
function requireValidator($value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        return 'Required value'
    }
    return true;
}

function emailValidator($value) {
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return 'This is not a valid email';
    }

    return true;
}

function numberValidator() and so on
...

function validate($fields, $input) { // And here is where the validation happens
    $errors = [];
    foreach ($userInputArray as $inputField => $inputValue) {
        foreach ($userInputField as $rule) {
             $validator = "{$rule}Validator";
             $result = $validator($inputValue);
             if ($result !== true) {
                  $errors[$inputField][] = $result;
             }
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

And then in your code:

```
require('validator.php');
$fields = require('fields.php');

$userInput = $_POST;

$errors = validate($fields['users'], $userInput);
if (!empty($errors)) {
    // Show errors to the user
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to show you is that you can create validation rules at one centrelized place, and validators at another centrelized place. That way if you need to make a change, you do it at one place. 
What I do in the validator() function is:

- take the rules and the user input
- traverse through all validation rules
- build each validation function by concatenating the name of the rule and the word 'Validator' (I put the word 'Validator' in order to mark the function as validator and make it unique. This is like convention).
- Call each validator $validator()
- And then take the error message if there is one.

This is some basis which you can step on. You can create more validators and rules and make it more sophisticated.

If you don't understand anything, please ask. You are doing a really good job, because for one week of PHP you know pretty much.

Good luck!

Comment: That is one complete answer! I think you should update `$result != true` to `$result !== true` though because won't the error message be considered `true` in this comparison?

Comment: Thank you! It is a good practice, but in this case no. Mainly because true and the error message are not equal.

Comment: Are you sure? Because `( 'test string' == true )` returns `true`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are right! Thanks for the comment! I edited my code

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, I only did this for the name but you can add more to this to suit your needs.

```
// Array to store any input validation errors
$errorArray = [];
$nameErr = "Name is required";

// test to see if the $_POST variable is set
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // test to see if the $_POST variable contains the key name
  if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
     if($_POST['name'] == "") {
       // error message for name is required.
       $errorArray[] = $nameErr;  
     } else {
       // there is a value for name do your regex here
     }
  }
}
// Use print_r function to see if there are any items in the errorArray for yourself     
// print_r($errorArray); 
// * count the values in the errorArray... this is where it will ensure that if there are any errors found it will not set the $name variable and will not call you other database functions.
if(count($errorArray > 0)) {
   // loop through the errorArray and display the errors you can customize this as you see fit.
   for($i = 0; $i < count($errorArray); $i++) {
     echo $errorArray[$i];
   }
} else {
    // Your form has been submitted.
    // no errors you can do database calls here.
    $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
    //<form action="DBInput.php" method="POST"  />
    // try not using the form action DBInput and make a function call instead passing in each value you need.
   doDataBaseStuff($name);
}
```

And then your function...

```
function doDataBaseStuff($name) {
   // do database stuff....
}
```